# app using hibernate 5.4.27.Final is not deploying successful in wildfly-11.0.0.Final

Tags: java, hibernate, dialect, wildfly-11

I have an app (version 201908) deployed in wildfly-11.0.0.Final that's using org.hibernate-hibernate-core-3.6.9.Final and java 8 and is successfully deployed.

When I'm trying to deploy this app's newer version (202211), that's using org.hibernate-hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final, in the same wildfly-11.0.0.Final, still with java 8, with the same standalone.xml it gets stuck on this last line from here:

```
INFO  com.commons.utilities.persistence.HibernateUtils - Determining Hibernate dialect
INFO  com.commons.utilities.persistence.HibernateUtils - Using DialectFactory and DB properties to determine dialect
INFO  org.hibernate.Version - HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.27.Final
INFO  org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
INFO  com.commons.utilities.persistence.HibernateUtils - Chosen dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
INFO  com.commons.utilities.persistence.HibernateUtils - There are mapping resources, examining for SQLSERVER
INFO  org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
INFO  org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
```

And it's failing with a timeout:
[image]

On my machine, both versions are deploying successfully and logs are looking like this:

```
INFO  org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
INFO  org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
WARN  org.hibernate.id.UUIDHexGenerator - HHH000409: Using org.hibernate.id.UUIDHexGenerator which does not generate IETF RFC 4122 compliant UUID values; consider using org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator instead
INFO  org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableGenerator - HHH000398: Explicit segment value for id generator [hibernate_unique_key.sequence_name] suggested; using default [default]
INFO  org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableGenerator - HHH000398: Explicit segment value for id generator [hibernate_unique_key.sequence_name] suggested; using default [default]
INFO  org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableGenerator - HHH000398: Explicit segment value for id generator [hibernate_unique_key.sequence_name] suggested; using default [default]
INFO  org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableGenerator - HHH000398: Explicit segment value for id generator [hibernate_unique_key.sequence_name] suggested; using default [default]
INFO  org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableGenerator - HHH000398: Explicit segment value for id generator [hibernate_unique_key.sequence_name] suggested; using default [default]
INFO  com.commons.preferences.spring.PreferenceBasedPropertyOverrideConfigurer - Post-Processing the Bean Factory
INFO  com.commons.preferences.spring.PreferenceBasedPropertyOverrideConfigurer - Listing the DB-stored configuration overrides
INFO  org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator - HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.ConfigurableJtaPlatform]
........
```

I tried to increase the timeout, even the deployment-timeout in standalone.xml, but still not passing this line...
Anyone, any suggestion what I can try to make it work? Thanks!

Comment: That is a pretty big jump in WildFly. I'd suggest upgrading WildFly instead of Hibernate.

Comment: Well, I'm not in a position to change anything in the application. I just need to update the app to a client from a certain version that have that hibernate to a newer version with hibernate 5.4.27.Final. The point is that on my machine, it is working with wildfly 11. The application being with java 8, I know that newer versions of wildfly need at least java 11.

Comment: WildFly 26 is Jakarta EE 8 and works on Java 8. WildFly 27+ is Jakarta EE 10 and requires Java 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling more logs found that was something related to the XA of my database. I changed in  my active datasource to point toward a non-xa datasource and it worked.